# error installing php dependencies on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, terminal-server

I have a vps with `linux ubuntu 20.04 LTS` installed, I also installed the lamp stack to upload my web projects, php with version 7.4, now I need to install some more php libraries for example: `php-gd` so run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd
```

but when installing I get the following error: `php7.4-cli : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18) but 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.17 is to be installed`

and actually it won't let me install anything else, because it always throws me that error.. any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/apt/sources.list` and see if it contains a line this:

```
deb http://... focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

The line make look slightly different, but most important is that you have the **focal-security** repository enabled, since version 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18 is available there.

Then update the repo `apt update` and try again `apt install php7.4-gd`.

Comment: I don't have that line added, what should I do? should i register it?

Comment: Yes, add:

`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse`

and run `apt update` and `apt install php7.4-gd`

Answer (score 0):

First Install software-properties-common package on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

You can try adding **ondrej/php** PPA for **PHP 7.4** in your **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

Once update completes, run the following to install PHP 7.4

```
sudo apt install -y \
php7.4 \
php7.4-bcmath \
php7.4-bz2 \
php7.4-cgi \
php7.4-cli \
php7.4-curl \
php7.4-fpm \
php7.4-gd \
php7.4-gettext \
php7.4-intl \
php7.4-ldap \
php7.4-mbstring \
php7.4-mysql \
php7.4-opcache \
php7.4-pgsql \
php7.4-soap \
php7.4-xml \
php7.4-zip
```

Once Installation completes you can use the following commands to check, If **PHP 7.4** Installed or not `php -v`

Comment: when i run: sudo apt-get install software-properties-common,i also get the mentioned error

Comment: @FeRcHo

Try using these commands first

`sudo apt-get purge php7.* && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Once it completes, Try the commands provided in the solution. 

**sudo apt-get purge** - It removes the package as well as its configuration files

**sudo apt-get autoclean** - It cleans obsolete deb-packages.

**sudo apt-get autoremove** - It removes orphaned packages which are no longer needed